# WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, cdi, wildfly-9

I losted many time try solve this issuer, but I am in the same place. I suspect that I mixed something of CDI with EJB.

The problem is persist and delete only don't work.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:866)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:579)
    at com.oki.scope.console.model.dao.GenericDAO.save(GenericDAO.java:29)
    at com.oki.scope.console.model.dao.GenericConsoleDAO.save(GenericConsoleDAO.java:12)
    at com.oki.scope.console.service.ServidorServiceImp.salvar(ServidorServiceImp.java:27)
    at com.oki.scope.console.service.ServidorServiceImp$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.salvar(Unknown Source)
    at com.oki.scope.console.managedBean.consulta.ServidorMB.salvar(ServidorMB.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 40 more
```

My DAO

```
public class GenericDAO<T, K> {

    protected EntityManager em;
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass,  EntityManager em) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    protected void save(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }
```

Generic DAO:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public abstract class GenericConsoleDAO<T, K> extends GenericDAO<T, K> {

     public GenericConsoleDAO(Class<T> entityClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityClass, em);
    }

    public void save(T t){
        super.save(t);
    }

}
```

DAO Factory:

```
package com.oki.scope.console.model.dao;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class DAOConsoleFactory {
    private final static String UNIT_NAME = "scope-console";

    private static Map<String, Object> mapa = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Object>());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = UNIT_NAME )  
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces public ServidorDAO            criaServidorDAO(){          return getDAO(ServidorDAO.class); }
    @Produces public ConexaobdDAO           criaConexaoDAO(){           return getDAO(ConexaobdDAO.class);      }
    @Produces public ContratoDAO            criaContratoDAO(){          return getDAO(ContratoDAO.class);   }
    @Produces public EmpresaDAO             criaEmpresaDAO(){           return getDAO(EmpresaDAO.class); }
    @Produces public LojaDAO                criaLojaDAO(){              return getDAO(LojaDAO.class);   }
    //@Produces public RedeAutorizadoraDAO  criaRedeAutorizadoraDAO(){  return getDAO(RedeAutorizadoraDAO.class); }
    @Produces public RedeDAO                criaRedeDAO(){              return getDAO(RedeDAO.class);   }
    @Produces public RoteadorDAO            criaRoteadorDAO(){          return getDAO(RoteadorDAO.class);   }
    @Produces public TerminalDAO            criaTerminalDAO(){          return getDAO(TerminalDAO.class);   }
    @Produces public TipoHeaderDAO          criaTipoHeaderDAO(){        return getDAO(TipoHeaderDAO.class);     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <E> E getDAO(Class<E> classe){
        String key = classe.getSimpleName();
        if (!mapa.containsKey(key))
        {
            try {
                mapa.put(key, classe.getDeclaredConstructor(EntityManager.class).newInstance(entityManager));
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                System.out.println("Classe "+ key +" não possui um construtor que tenha EntityManager como parametro.");
            }
        }
        return (E)mapa.get(key);

    }
}
```

My class:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServidorServiceImp implements ServidorService {

    @Inject private ServidorDAO dao;


    @Override
    public List<Servidor> getLista() {
        return dao.getLista();
    }

    @Override
    public void salvar(Servidor servidor) {
        if (servidor.getId()==0){
            dao.save(servidor);
        }
        else
        {
            dao.update(servidor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remover(Servidor servidor) {
        dao.delete(servidor);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

In trying to enhance performance, you have circumvented what the container is supposed to be doing for you, which is instantiating a bean inside a transaction.

I would say remove the `@Singleton` and `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` from `DAOConsoleFactory` and allow the EJB transaction to be handled by the EJB bean that's using the DAO's.

UPDATE: Also, `@ApplicationScoped` is not an EJB annotation Class `ServidorServiceImp` needs to be an EJB bean so, it should be annotated with `@Stateless` or perhaps `@Statefull` and remove the `@ApplicationScoped`. It reads like a stateless EJB bean, so there is no need to make it application scoped.

Again, it seems to me you are concentrating too much on trying to optimize performance without having a good understanding of how EJB's are supposed to work in a container. I would recommend getting everything to work and follow architectural best practices, especially in the "Session Façade" concept. Some of these posts may help: [What is the point of a Facade in Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798184/what-is-the-point-of-a-facade-in-java-ee?rq=1) or [Why use Facade pattern for EJB session bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636764/why-use-facade-pattern-for-ejb-session-bean?rq=1).

Comment: I removed the both notes. That's prove that @TransactionManagement was unused. The problem keep the same.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: Before 2 day suffering. The problem was in my Class. Where is @Named
@ApplicationScoped, I changed to @Statefull.

Comment: Hi buddy, It could sound rude, but, your implementations are very poor. Just take a look at this book (http://realworldpatterns.com/) and you will understand all the misused patterns and the boilerplate code that you have, I recommend you the chapters related to DAO and SessionBean and Facade patterns.